# Change user slug in Buddypress

Tags: users, buddypress, slug

I am creating a site with Buddypress. Everything is going good so far but default member slug for buddypress is `domain.com/members/abc`. I want that it as `domain.com/abc` like facebook and twitter. Any one can help me for that.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'bp_core_enable_root_profiles', '__return_true' );
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just curious to know if this helped?

Comment: Man you are great. It worked.......